# The file came from another computer and might be blocked

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint

I have received a file of type `PPT`. When I try to change the content it doesn't open with Microsoft PowerPoint, but directly goes to the slide show. When I check the properties of that file, it says "The file came from another computer and might be blocked".

Please let me know how I can edit it with PowerPoint.

Answer (score 5):

Click the button that says "unblock" and it should open fine.

[image]